# Apache Flink dataStream.sinkTo() is not accepting the KafkaSink<String> as an argument. It is expecting Sink<String, ?, ?, ?>

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Apache Flink. I am trying to stream data from Kafka, do something on Flink and publish the data to some other topic in Kafka.

Below are the dependencies added

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Code

```
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        KafkaSource<String> kafkaSource = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                .setTopics("webapp-analytics")
                .setDeserializer(KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema.valueOnly(StringDeserializer.class))
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                .build();

        DataStreamSource<String> source = env.fromSource(kafkaSource, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");

        DataStream<String> finalStream = source.filter(new FilterFunction<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean filter(String s) throws Exception {
                return s.contains("clicked");
            }
        });

        KafkaSink<String> sink = KafkaSink.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                .setRecordSerializer(KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
                        .setTopic("flink")
                        .setValueSerializationSchema(new SimpleStringSchema())
                        .build()
                )
                .setDeliveryGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
                .build();

        finalStream.sinkTo(sink);

        env.execute("Kafka");
    }
}
```

Now the issue what I am facing here is `finalStream.sinkTo();` method is not accepting the KafkaSink object as an argument. It is expecting the argument as `Sink<String, ?, ?, ?>`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From dependencies, it looks like you're mixing Flink 1.14.6 with Flink 1.17.1. Make everything 1.17.1, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Issue got resolved after replacing the ```<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.6</version>
    </dependency>``` with ```<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>```